# Sass Preprocessors - Can They Ignore Specific Patterns?

Tags: sass, liquid, codekit, libsass

I'm using CodeKit to compile .scss using libsass.  In these files I want to include some Liquid templating

```
.some-class {
    color: {{ settings.color_primary }};
}
```

Throws and error though.  Is there a way to tell the preprocessor to let this pass through?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sass [interpolations](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Interpolation_____) to insert anything literally

```
.some-class {
    color: #{ "{{ settings.color_primary }}" };
}
```

You may also use a helper function for nicer syntax

```
@function liquid-var($name) {
    @return #{ "{{ " + $name + " }}" };
}

.some-class {
    color: liquid-var("settings.color_primary");
}
```